# JavaScript Function Not Firing Properly On HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, url, query-string

When a link is clicked I want to do 2 things; fire a Pixel event that passes an item id, and attach an `href` url and go to that link. Both the Pixel event and the url will need a parameter passed.

I get the last query string parameter appended from the inbound URL to this page, and then I try to convert it into the `itemId` variable.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**JavaScript**

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', pEvents);
function pEvents() {
  function fnView() {

    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var utm_content;

    if (queryString !== null) {

      utm_content = queryString.match(/utm_content=([^&]+)/)[1];
      console.log(utm_content);
      var itemId = utm_content.toString();
      console.log(itemId)

      //Pixel tracking with parameter included
      snaptr('track', 'VIEW_CONTENT', {
        'item_ids': itemId
      });

    } else {

      //Pixel tracking without the parameter just in case
      snaptr('track', 'VIEW_CONTENT');

    }

    // [].slice.call(document.getElementById('link')).find(e => {
    //   if (e.innerText == "Let's go!") {
    //     e.addEventListener('mouseenter', fnView);
    //     e.href = "https://www.sitedomain1.com/m-pr.cfm?m=91020&u=2346350&p=" & itemId;
    //    }
    //  })

      if (e.innerText == "Let's go!") {
        e.addEventListener('mouseenter', fnView);
        e.href = "https://www.sitedomain1.com/m-pr.cfm?m=91020&u=2346350&p=" & itemId;
    }

  };
};
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="link" href="#">Let's go!</a>
```

Comment: Where is your click event handler?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with `[].slice.call()`. `document.getElementById()` doesn't return an array-like object, it returns a single DOM element.

Comment: The callback function for `find()` is supposed to return `true` or `false`. It seems like you want `forEach()`. But there's no need for a loop, since `getElementById()` only returns a single element.

Comment: If you have multiple `id="link"` elements, you need to change that to a class.

Comment: @Barmar I thought the `a` tag would handle the click, I was attempted to use `a.href` to declare the dynamic url that should be used but I do not believe this is working. Also, I've updated my code above, I grabbed it from an old project. Still not working though, any thoughts?

Comment: Where so you set `e` now that you removed the `filter()` call?

Comment: The code that adds the event listener should not be inside the `fnView` function.